# Transforming long table into wide format with counts for only one column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, reshape2, dcast

I have a table in long format  as shown below, every row is unique in this input table :-

```
 year variable
  2014   ab  
  2014   cd  
  2014   ef 
  2016   ef 
  2016   gh
  2014   ab  
  2014   cd  
  2014   ef 
  2016   ef 
  2016   gh
```

I would like convert this table into wide format but only for `variable` column which looks like a contigency matrix. For example - As shown in the output table below, the combination of ab+cd appears ONCE for year 2014, and the combination of ab+ef also appears Once for year 2014. In that way, the first row of my output table clearly shows all the `Counts` for different combinations `variable` column of input table for different years.

```
year    value  ab  cd  ef  gh  
2014    ab     2    2   2   0
2014    cd     2    2   2   0 
2014    ef     2    2   2   0 
2014    ef     0    0   2   2 
2016    gh     0    0   2   2
```

I have tried to reshape table quite a few times but have not been able to achieve the result that I want to have. I would very much appreciate if the solution includes use of `data.table`. Thank you.

Comment: Your desired output seems to be inconstant with the input. For instance in 2014 both `cd` and `ef` are present, yet in your output the corresponding cells have a `0`

Comment: Thanks. I changed it.

Comment: Shouldn't "ef+cd" be 1, as "cd+ef" ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
vs <- DT[, unique(variable)]
for (x in vs) set(DT, j=x, value=0L)
DT[, (vs) := {
        m <- as.matrix(.SD)
        m[, match(variable, vs)] <- 1L
        as.data.table(m)
    }, year, .SD=vs]
DT
```

And also:

```
DT[, (vs) := {
        m <- copy(.SD)
        m[, match(variable, vs)] <- 1L
        m
    }, year, .SD=vs]
```

output as per problem description (as pointed out by Daniel O and meriops, there are some inconsistencies between the desired output and problem description):

```
   year variable ab cd ef gh
1: 2014       ab  1  1  1  0
2: 2014       cd  1  1  1  0
3: 2014       ef  1  1  1  0
4: 2016       ef  0  0  1  1
5: 2016       gh  0  0  1  1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("year variable
2014   ab  
2014   cd  
2014   ef 
2016   ef 
2016   gh")
```

Comment: Hey, I think it will take time for me to understand the code. I am fairly new to this. Can I know how the code can be changed further to get the numbers same as contigency table instead of 1 or 0? Thanks again.

Comment: i might need some time to understand contingency table. is it possible for you to update your example to show an example?

Comment: I changed the input and output data example. As you can see that instead of getting sparse matrix consisting of 1 and 0 from your code. I want to have reduced matrix that includes sum of number of appearance of said combinations. I hope it is clear. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @newbie, what would be the expected output for `fread("year variable\n
2014   ab\n  
2014   cd\n  
2014   ef\n 
2014   ab")`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want ef-cd cells to be `1` and not `0`, here's a slightly tortured approach using `igraph` and `tidyverse`. The idea is to create a bipartite graph, find the 1-mode projection, and create an adjacency matrix from that projection:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

df <- tibble(year = c("2014",
                "2014",
                "2014",
                "2016",
                "2016"),
             variable = c("ab",
                          "cd",
                          "ef",
                          "ef",
                          "gh"))

tab <- df %>% 
  group_split(year) %>% 
  map(~ .x %>% 
        graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>% 
        set_vertex_attr("type", value = ifelse(V(.)$name %in% .x$year, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
        bipartite_projection(which = FALSE) %>% 
        add_edges(rep(1:length(unique(.x$variable)), 2) %>% sort()) %>% 
        as_adjacency_matrix(sparse = FALSE) %>% 
        as_tibble()) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate_all(coalesce, 0)

cbind(df, tab)
#>   year variable ab cd ef gh
#> 1 2014       ab  1  1  1  0
#> 2 2014       cd  1  1  1  0
#> 3 2014       ef  1  1  1  0
#> 4 2016       ef  0  0  1  1
#> 5 2016       gh  0  0  1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

```
df <- data.table(df)
df_dcast <- dcast.data.table(df,year~value,fun=length)
```

Comment: No, this isn't correct. You are converting whole input table into plain wide format. The output table includes the combination of ab+cd and ab+ef

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code in `Base R` that accomplishes this task

```
df_new <- t(sapply(unique(df$year), function(X) lapply(unique(df$variable), function(Y)  length(which(df$variable== Y & df$year == X)))))
row.names(df_new) <- unique(df$year)
colnames(df_new) <- unique(df$variable)
```

output:

```
     ab cd ef gh
2014 1  1  1  0 
2016 0  0  1  1
```

Input Data:

```
Input = (
  ' year variable
  2014   ab  
  2014   cd  
  2014   ef 
  2016   ef 
  2016   gh')
df = read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T)
```

Comment: I am interested in combinations of counts within `variable` column and not the counts for overall `year` column. You are missing the second column of my output table shown in question.